# Why is there no output of print tensorflow queue?

Tags: tensorflow

My code looks like below. When I run it the first time, there is output, but when I run it a second time, there is no output.

**My Code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
q = tf.FIFOQueue(3, "float")
init = q.enqueue_many(([0., 0., 0.],))
x = q.dequeue()
y = x +1
q_inc = q.enqueue([y])

sess.run(init)
sess.run(q_inc)
sess.run(q_inc)
sess.run(q_inc)
sess.run(q_inc)
for i in range(0, 4):
  print(sess.run(q.dequeue()))
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting capacity as `3`, it can't store more than 3 element. When you try to execute the the `dequeue` op for the 4th time, the program freezes. You can increase the `capacity` of thge queue.

```
# Dont forget to reset the default graph
tf.reset_default_graph()
capacity = 3
q = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity, "float")
```

Note: If you run this prgram from cli, it prints 3 elements and freezes every time, increasing the queue capcity would solve the same.

Comment: dear @Ishant Mrinal  ,thank you for your answer. by the way , can you tell me how to unfreeze the program? i find that when the program is freezed, i close the notebook ,and open it next time, but the program is still no output.